# Bulk Insert with Format File (Fixed Width) - Unexpected end of file was encountered

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, bcp

```
BULK INSERT [Alldlyinventory] 
   FROM     'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\2NobleEstates\DATA\Download\Output\test.txt' 
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\SQL Data\FormatFiles\test.xml');
```

Format file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="7"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="10"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="DAY_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="LCBO_NO" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="LOCATION_NUMBER" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LISTING_STATUS" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="QTY_ON_HAND" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

But I am getting the following error on SQL Server 2014:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

It's a fixed width import.

Sample txt:

```
2016032803170570371L 000000014
2016032803367430371L 000000013
2016032803403800371L 000000036
2016032804007540371L 000000015
```

Comment: Let me state the obvious? **The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.**

Comment: Sorry, this is a fixed width bulk insert

Comment: Your txt file might be having blank at the end. Can you use the `ERRORFILE` and find the row that is causing the problem ? Also try using `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'` (undocumented though) to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, there's a blank at the end. 
I got the error: Row 1269290 File Offset 38078670 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005. Please see sample data as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your sample text file, it looks like you have a row terminator that is carriage return (`{CR}`) + linefeed (`{LF}`).

You can inspect this by opening the text file with a text editor that can show special symbols. I can recommend [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which is free and good for this purpose (Menu `View>Show Symbol>Show All Characters`).

If the row terminator is indeed `{CR}{LF}`, you should use `xsi:type="CharTerm"` along with a `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` attribute for the last `<FIELD>` in the `<RECORD>` element:

```
<RECORD>
    ...
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
</RECORD>
```

---

You can find more information on fixed field import in the following link: [XML Format Files (SQL Server) # Importing fixed-length or fixed-width fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server#ImportFixedFields)

Comment: Hi, the data does end with {CR}{LF} but I am getting the following error: Attribute "ROWTERMINATOR" could not be specified for this type. After, I changed the ROWTERMINATOR to TERMINATOR and it worked. Thanks alot. I really appreciate this forum and the people here.

Comment: @Ben Ah yes you are correct, the correct attribute is `TERMINATOR` (answer updated). Glad it helped =).